# Does VS 2017 support break point debugging of node.js typescript code of a merged file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on VS 2015 and debugging a node.js typescript app that merges all my typescript files into a single JS file.

Whenever I start debugging my node.js project, VS 2015 tells me that debugging merged JS files in typescript is not supported yet. This means i have to add breakpoints to the original JS file when debugging, as opposed to using the original typescript files.

I was wondering if 2017 has that scenario enabled now. I don't want to have to deal with the hassle of upgrading to 2017 just to find out that i still can't debug merged typescript files in node.js with VS 2017.

Any insights from anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally updated to VS 2017. Turns out sadly that the answer is no.